# Multiple resource files in C#

Tags: c#, localization, embedded-resource

I have been searching answers for similar questions, but the questions are either fairly old or unanswered.

**Background**

We have a few different websites sharing the same code base and they are hosted separately. All of the sites are in English, but they all have localised contents (such as UK, AUS & NZ). The localised contents may include email address, phone number and different company.

The code has hardcoded to separate contents with localised controls such as lit_PhoneAU, lit_PhoneNZ & lit_PhoneUK. There are codes to hide & show these controls based on the location config.

**Problem**
What was coded worked for what we needed before, but it has its limitation and isn't expandable.

We like to use a mix of resource files and object properties populated by database table. It's fairly straight forward to load some common stuff with the database call, but it's best to use something like resource file to store something more specific and literal.

**Question**
My understanding of C# resource file is we can switch resource file based on the localisation setting such en-AU, en-UK, fr-fr and so on. However, they won't fit our purposes as we may have multiple sites for a single location.

Is there way we can easily switch between resource files? or I have misunderstood the use of resource files? or is there any other way you can suggest to manage literal contents.

**Updates**

I must make it very clear. My question isn't about switching the UiCulture as we already have code in place to handle that. This is about handling multiple resources within the same Culture. For example, we have the same code base for two different site in UK. Site A is about Division A and it may be SiteA.co.uk and have the Site Title as Company A, then Site B is another division of a company and the site maybe siteB.co.uk. It's super inefficient to manage the contents at the moment, so we are trying to move the contents into resource files or business object populated by database calls.

Comment: After some fairly extensive research, I found this post is very close to what I need. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402451/how-can-i-change-resource-files-for-a-c-sharp-winform-app-without-changing-the It shows there is a way creating custom culture. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172469(v=vs.90).aspx. I still like to hear if someone has a better answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use google translate (free) to your website. It will automatically convert the content to desired language. Just go through the documentation. Otherwise I think some paid translator is available..

Comment: Could you give a demo with C# code calling the Google Translater web service?

Comment: After some fairly extensive research, I think I found this post to be something similar to what I need.

Comment: Great Jack. Jeremy go through this [link](http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-translation-widgets/10135/) .Firstly you will register with google [link](https://translate.google.com/manager/website/) A simple example for javascript is shown below

Comment: `<div id="google_translate_element" style="float:right;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', includedLanguages: 'ar', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>
<scripttype="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the localization that you need in Global.asax.cs, before a request occurred.

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Sets default culture to en-UK
    string culture = "en-UK";

    //Here you can choose the culture as you want.
    //If you don't want to have another culture, you can specify a default of any culture, and .resx files will use it.

    //In this example, I check if the culture is the fr-fr we use it, otherwise use en-UK.
    //Try to get values from Accept lang HTTP header
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages != null &&
        HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages.Length != 0)
    {
        //Gets accepted list 
        string name = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages[0];
        if (name.Equals("fr-fr", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            culture = "fr-fr";
    }

    CultureInfo info = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(culture);
    //Finally setting culture for each request
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = info;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = info;
}
```

Then you can use the *Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture* to retrieve data from a database that conforms to the culture.

Comment: I have to make it clear again. it's nothing to do with the location of the resource. We have code in place to switch the UiCulture already, but it's not about switch the Culture. I have updated the my question above

Comment: I could have hacked it and used different cultures for different instances, but it's not ideal and may have some unexpected results. Therefore, en-AU for siteA and then fr-fr for site B.